# how to properly redirect to page in asp.netcore

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

edit:background on project. This was project was created following the concepts from the tutorials here on data access with razor pages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/?view=aspnetcore-2.2. i did not do views or controllers so I currently do not have any actions i can redirect to. do i need to add a controllers folder?

When I save changes to my edit of the model `subcategories`, I want to go back to the `categories` page. Normally, this would be fine with a simple `RedirectToPage("/index")`.

That doesn't work here because my index `OnGet` uses a string ID to filter through the the `subcategories` (which feels like I'm probably doing that wrong... but it works). Below is what I currently have and it obviously doesn't work:

Edit - **OnPost:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Attach(Subcategory).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!SubcategoryExists(Subcategory.SubcategoryId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./Index", "?id" , Subcategory.CategoryName);
}
```

Index - **OnGet:**

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string id)
{
    title = id;

    Subcategory = await _context.Subcategory.ToListAsync();

    foreach (Subcategory item in Subcategory.ToList())
    {
        if (item.CategoryName != id)
        {
           Subcategory.Remove(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me how to properly route the `OnPost` of my edit razor page to the `OnGet` of my index razor page?

I've tried to do some research on handlers but I couldn't find a good understandable definition of how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit hard to see where you have hooked stuff up, as you have only provided the methods.

Given that `OnGetAsync(string id)` if mapped to `/index` you could use something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = Subcategory.CategoryName.ToString() });
```

I would also suggest that you call your methods the same as the endpoint. So if `OnGetAsync` is your index endpoint. Then call it `Index`.

Hopefully this helps you, or else you need to provide me with more code.

Comment: /index is a razor page im redirecting to. i currently am not using mvc ergo i have no actions?

Comment: @SamuelWakeman From all I know RedirectToPage comes from the MVC Framework? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagebase.redirecttopage?view=aspnetcore-2.2  If this is not the case. Can you edit your question to include what kind of framework you are using? I am shooting in the dark right now without that information.

Comment: huh... i guess it is? but i currently have no controllers and actions should i add one?

Comment: @SamuelWakeman I would suggest that you follow the pattern of the MVC framework if you want to use razor views. This simplifies a lot of these processes for you and makes it easier to see the bindings (all of it will be checked at compile time). So yes I think using the controllers will make things easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

the fix to the problem without building a controller was pretty much what Kristian Barrnet was saying:

```
   return RedirectToPage("./Index", new { id = Subcategory.CategoryName.ToString() });
```

however, I should probably add some controllers here anyway to make this a lot more organized