# .Net redirection returns view back to api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm creating temporary API for testing purposes which uses swagger. The API is supposed to take in some data and than redirect user to other project with MVC Controller which returns View. The problem is view gets returned to swagger response even thought I redirected to the MVC. So view is not loaded but rather returned like a plain text. My question is, is it possible to load the returned view or did I make logical mistake.

Here is my code snippets:

Temporary API Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("tempAction")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveActionTempInfo(TempInputParam sessionParam)
        {
                var response = doSomethingWithData(sessionParam);

                if (response)
                {
                    var url = geturl(); // MVC Index URL
                    return Redirect(url);
                }

                return BadRequest();
        }
```

MVC Action:

```
[HttpGet("{sessionId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sessionId)
        {
            return View("Index", sessionId);
        }
```

Comment: Redirection within Controller is possible by using RedirectToAction [Similar question with answer can be found at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280717/asp-net-core-mvc-redirecttoaction-is-appending-controller-name-in-front-of-retur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280717/asp-net-core-mvc-redirecttoaction-is-appending-controller-name-in-front-of-retur) and [another example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675724/how-to-properly-redirect-to-page-in-asp-netcore)

Comment: You mean when you use swagger to call SaveActionTempInfo,you will get text result of Index View?If so,you can try to call SaveActionTempInfo without swagger.

Comment: @Thiam RedirectToAction is not possible as this two controllers are in different projects.

Comment: @Yiyi yes that's the route I fixed it with, I created temporary mvc view where I'm inputting the data json and redirection works just fine. I think it has to do with being API and Swagger. From my point of view swagger was always expecting the answer, even thought it was redirected, so the view return was actually returning in swagger as plain text.